# Is there a java sqlite3 library for ARM Linux available?

Tags: java, linux, sqlite, arm

I need to create and manage a sqlite3 DB in Java on ARM Linux.
I would prefer a library that can be used seamlessly both on ARM Linux and on x86 Windows (32 or 64bit, for the development and testing) and that support SQL queries.
I know there are [sqlitejdbc](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) and [sqlite-jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/) but it seems their distributions do not come with ARM Linux support.
There is also [sqljet](http://sqljet.com/) that is a pure java (w/o native code) but it uses a dedicated API instead of SQL.
Essentially, I'm looking something equivalent to sqlite3 python module.
Does it exist ?

Comment: For pure Java with SQL access, if SQLite is not mandatory, you could try HSQLDB or Derby...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just took a look at sqlite4java, which seems to fit the bill: SQL and pure Java.

http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/

Anyway, you can take a look here to find what you need:

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers

but sqlite4java seems to be the most active project.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR, `sqlitejdbc` can run in pure java mode (without the need of native libraries).

You can also utilize [Xerial](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) driver with `-Dsqlite.purejava=true` system property set.